# ASP.net MVC - Attribute not mapped into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have an attribute in a Model that is not mapped into a column in database?

I am using ASP.net Entity Framework with MVC 5.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Code First or Designer? The answer is yes but need more details.

Comment: I am using ASP.net Entity Framework with MVC 5, Code first.

Comment: But is it code first or model first?

Comment: Yes, that will depend on how you architecture your solution. explain more about your code structure?

Comment: Code First is what I am using.

Comment: Though this answer is the same as the linked question's answer, the other question is about MVC3 and this one is about MVC5.  As someone learning ASP.NET now, after it's been around for decades, I try to avoid anything older than the current versions of things, as they're often obsolete, deprecated, or otherwise part of the dustbin of history.  I therefore disagree that this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`NotMapped`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public int MappedProperty { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int UnmappedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively using the fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel>().Ignore(m => m.UnmappedProperty );
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```